# Удалить сайт из выдачи

Tags: seo, веб-программирование, поисковые-системы

Здравствуйте. Делал сайт и пока шла разработка он размещался на тестовом хостинге. Сейчас сайт уже в продакшене. Гугл его проиндексировал, проиндексировал и тестовый) И тестовый выдается раньше продакшена)) Домен с тестовым уже удалил. Остается просто ждать или можно как-то проявить инициативу раньше? Просто надо показывать заказчику и не хочется ему это объяснять.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используйте 301 редирект в .htaccess
Это ускорит понимание поисковиков, что ресурс переехал

Comment: @Demyan112rv, спасибо. Попробую

Comment: @Demyan112rv, если тестовый домен тебе ещё подконтролен то вариант с 301 редиректом должен сработать. Ну и вариант с гугловыми инструментами для веб-мастеров попробуй. одно другому не мешает.

Если домена больше нет (например это было что-то временное выданное хостером вроде seehingo.user.example.com) то остаётся только ждать.

Answer (score 0):

Зарегистрируйте сайт в инструментах гугла для веб-мастеров, там есть раздел удалить URLы - воспользуйтесь им. В robots запретите индексацию уже не существующих страниц что бы поисковик на 404е не ругался.

Answer (score 0):

Однажды столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой и решил ее так:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

- Указанный тэг размещаем на всех страницах;
- Создаем новый `sitemap.xml` (если нет старого), указываем его в `robots.txt` и обязательно делаем `Resumbit`-ы файла `sitemap.xml`.

Через пару дней цель будет достигнута - все проиндексированные страницы будут удалены из результатов поисков.

Answer (score 0):

На тестовую страницу в роботсе (http://loleknbolek.com/slovar-terminov/chto-takoe-fajl-robots-txt-kak-ego-sozdat-i-nastroit/) поместите строку:
Disallow: /
+ в гугл вебмастере удалите все проиндексированные урлы